# the event listener benchmark in different JPA ? Is hibernate the fastest?

Tags: performance, hibernate, events

Is there benchmark on event listener callback  between hibernate and Spring Data JPA approach and pure jpa and other approach?

I am using hibernate now in production for 4 years and I wonder if we have some more effective way to do so now.

Comment: After 4 years in production why do you care about benchmarks ))

Comment: If it' works live it as it. If you have  issues ple give a cases

Comment: Spring data works over hibernate ,evens  it 's part of hibernate.  Propably in same cases spring data does some exrtra work instead of pure hibernate but it's some specific cases

Comment: We all know there are several alternative orm framework.

Comment: We all know there are several alternative orm framework. We consider to implement a database trigger like feature .with hibernate event system is much slower and not reliable I think, if you want to do some complex work for example  table record find,insert or update.

Comment: Triger it's native database mechanism. It works faster then hibernate. If you use events do something extra with database and you dont need hibernate context.

Comment: In our current project we moved audits into db level  only when we figurout that events does some performance issues and we did't  use hibernate context for nothing except audit.

Comment: In our current project we moved audits into db level  only when we figurout that events does some performance issues and we did't  use hibernate context for nothing except audit.

Comment: just advice - before doing refactoring / changes , collect statistic for call execution time (before refactoring) and it you can - save it in db somewhere. after refactoring do the same and compare statistic. you will see how time is changed. also log statistic helps to find bottleneck in code and you see what you can improve.

Comment: So the sugarcrm,dynamiccrm,saleforce etc. implement trigger based on data_base triggers?? I do a bit search online but I don't find any clue. what do you think?

Comment: http://in.relation.to/2004/06/20/history-triggers-and-hibernate/

Comment: I dont know your architecture and requirements. Trigers might be use as variant in some cases.